# SIP how to measure call per time unit

Tags: sip, packet, throughput

I need to send a big number of SIP requests to our server for testing purposes. One solution I've found is SIPp. Now I want to measure the number of SIP requests that can be sent by my client per unit of time. SIPp gives the possibility to set the call-rate but I know that there are also physical limitations(client CPU, network card, ...). That's what I want to test first.
I think that this question can be extended to : how to measure the number of packets sent by one client per unit of time.
I thought about using Wireshark by counting the number of sent SIP INVITE packets during one second (using the time column) but I don't know what the precision of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark (or tshark/tcpdump/etc) should work; they record the packets actually sent on the wire and when they were sent.

Comment: But what about the timestamp precision?

Comment: Generally (depends on OS, hardware) wireshark traces have been accurate to the millisecond (or better) in my esperience.

Comment: I've read on the wireshark documentation, that the timestamping is based on the data captured with WinPCAP. So the question becomes, what is the timestamping precision of WinPCAP? An accuracy of 1 millisecond is not enough for some measurements. For example, if I use a DNS queries simulator, and I want to determine the maximum number of queries that can be sent by my computer per second, because in general we need to send about 50000 qps, an accuracy of 1 millisecond is not enough.